# Can wildcard anonymous functions be used when parameters are repeating in the result expression?

Tags: scala, anonymous-function

Find Square of an integer 'x'.

1. Without Placeholder
   `var square = (x:Int) => x*x` 
   square(3) gives desired output 9.
2. With Placeholder `var square = (_:Int)*(_:Int)`
   square(3) gives Error 
   Not enough arguments for method apply: (v1: Int, v2: Int)Int in trait Function2.
   Unspecified value parameter v2.

Internally what is happening?

Comment: IMHO, people tend to abuse the `_` syntax on **Scala**. I would recommend you to do not use it too much, it really only makes sense for very simple expressions. In general, is better to be a little bit more verbose and give proper names to your arguments.

Answer (score 2):

No, each occurrence of `_` represents the next argument in the argument list for the function.

`(_:Int)*(_:Int)` is a function that takes two `Int` arguments and multiplies them.